# navigationLink to tag in another view

Tags: swift, tags, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview

Here's an edited version of the question. I'm working in Swiftui and I have two views. The first has two NavigationLinks. The second link is where I get stuck. I would like that link to go to 'tabTwo' on PageTwo. Getting to PageTwo isn't an issue... it's getting to tabTwo as a view on that page.

Here's an edited down contentView file:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isNavigationBarHidden: Bool = true
    @State private var selectedTab = ""

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        NavigationLink("Link One", destination: PageTwo()).padding(10)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                            .background(Color.white)
                        Divider().frame(width: 300,height: 1).background(Color.black)
                    }
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        NavigationLink("Link Two", destination: PageTwo())
                            .padding(10)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                            .background(Color.white)
                    }
// If you remove the below VStack everything works.
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        NavigationLink("Page Two tabTwo", destination: PageTwo(), tag: "tabTwo", selection: $selectedTab?)
                            .padding(10)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                            .background(Color.white)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Hidden Title")
        .navigationBarHidden(self.isNavigationBarHidden)
        .onAppear {self.isNavigationBarHidden = true}
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

and here's an edited down PageTwo:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PageTwo: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @State var isNavigationBarHidden: Bool = true
    @State private var selectedTab = ""

    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack() {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                //---> Tab One
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    VStack{
                        Text("PAGE ONE")
                            .padding(.bottom, 20)
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()})
                    { Text("BACK") }
                        .font(Font.system(size:14, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Hidden Title")
                .navigationBarHidden(self.isNavigationBarHidden)
                .onAppear {self.isNavigationBarHidden = true}
                .tabItem {Label("ONE", systemImage: "circle.fill")}
                .tag("tabOne")
                //---> Tab Two
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    VStack{
                        Text("PAGE TWO")
                            .padding(.bottom, 20)
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()})
                    { Text("BACK") }
                        .font(Font.system(size:14, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Hidden Title")
                .navigationBarHidden(self.isNavigationBarHidden)
                .onAppear {self.isNavigationBarHidden = true}
                .tabItem {Label("TWO", systemImage: "circle.fill")}
                .tag("tabTwo")
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .never))
            .onAppear {self.isNavigationBarHidden = true}
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Hidden Title")
        .navigationBarHidden(self.isNavigationBarHidden)
        .onAppear {self.isNavigationBarHidden = true}
        .background(Color.gray)
        .opacity(0.75)
        .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .never))
    }
}

struct PageTwo_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PageTwo()
    }
}
```

This throws an error at the 'some view' level of:

Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project

I've submitted the report, but can't figure out how to do what I'd like. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I'm very new to programming of any sort really. I know a bit of html/css, but that's about it. I've just figured out NavigationView... sort of. I'm not sure what to include for a minimal reproducible example as the rest of the code works fine until I put that line in there. Xcode doesn't give me any specifics as to what the issue is, it simply says file a bug report.

Comment: That error is usually a typo it is impossible to help you with the line you have provided. Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)

Comment: When you get this error that means you have a compilation or running error somewhere in your code. Try to build and/or run to find the error.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I've used a @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>  with a dismiss button to get a 'back' button working. Now if I can get the link to the tag working I'll have the whole thing solved! Oy vey.

Comment: I've edited the whole question and added some code... hopefully not too much. Maybe this helps figure things out.